# Initialisation  lists in constructors trying to initialize a structure

Tags: c++

g++ (GCC) 4.6.0

I have the following class and I am trying to initialize in my initialization list of my constructor.

```
class Floor_plan
{
private:
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;

    struct floor_size {
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;
    } floor;

public:
    Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor.x(0), floor.y(0) {} {}
    Floor_plan(unsigned int _width, unsigned int _height, unsigned int _x, unsigned int _y);
    ~Floor_plan() {};

    unsigned int get_floor_width();
    unsigned int get_floor_height();
    void set_floor_width(unsigned int _width);
    void set_floor_height(unsigned int height);

    void print_floorplan();
};
```

I have a structure I am trying to set the initial values to. However, I kept getting the following error:

```
expected ‘(’ before ‘.’ token
```

I have also tried doing it the following way:

```
Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), Floor_plan::floor.x(0), Floor_plan::floor.y(0) {}
```

However, that results in the following error:

```
expected class-name before ‘.’ token
```

Many thanks any suggestions,

Comment: Why don't you provide a constructor for floor_size ? Make it.               Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor(0, 0) {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [default init value for struct member of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846673/default-init-value-for-struct-member-of-a-class)

Either you initialize it inside the constructor

```
Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor() {
  floor.x = 1;
  floor.y = 2;
}
```

Or you create a constructor for the struct, and use that in the initialization list.

```
struct floor_size {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    floor_size(unsigned int x_, unsigned int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
} floor;

Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor(1, 2) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Give your struct  a constructor:

```
class Floor_plan
{
private:
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;

    struct floor_size {
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;

        floor_size( int ax, int ay ) : x(ax), y(ay) {}
    };

    floor_size floor;

public:
    Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor(0,0)  {} 
    Floor_plan(unsigned int _width, unsigned int _height, unsigned int _x, unsigned int _y);
    ~Floor_plan() {};

    unsigned int get_floor_width();
    unsigned int get_floor_height();
    void set_floor_width(unsigned int _width);
    void set_floor_height(unsigned int height);

    void print_floorplan();
};
```

IMHO, unless you really need the struct to be POD, it's good practice to always provide  a constructor - it simplifies things all over the place.

Comment: If he wants to initialize `floor` elements to zero (the default initializer for int), it doesn't need to define a constructor. The default constructor for the struct calls the default constructor for all members, which will zero the int member variables in `floor`.

Comment: Of course you don't *need* to define a constructor - I'm saying that you *should*.

Comment: @Juliano: "...calls the default constructor for all members" - not for the built-in types

Comment: @davka *including* built-in types. All C++ types have an implicit default constructor. For `int`s, as in this case, it initializes it to zero. It is precisely the difference between `new int` (uninitialized) and `new int()` (initialized to zero). That is also true for automatic variables. Check for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can only initialize floor, which is directly in the object being constructed.

```
Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor() {}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have enabled C++11 support, you can use `floor{0, 0}` [or, less explicitely, `floor { }`, similar to the `floor()` suggestions others mentioned]

```
class floor_plan {
    struct floor_size { int x, y; } floor;
public:
    floor_plan() : floor{0, 0} { }
    floor_plan(int i, int j) : floor{i, j} { }
};
```

Given your extraneous braces in your constructor, I suspect this is the syntax you were looking for.  No explicit constructor necessary (although you can now add one without sacrificing POD status, if that matters to you).

Answer (score 2):

You can **NEVER** do initialization using **dot(.)** ! Declare a constructor for `floor`.

```
struct floor_size
{
  floor_size(int, int);
}floor;
```

And use the same in the initializer list.

```
Floor_plan () : floor_size(0,0) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to declere a constructor for floor_size class and call that constructor.

Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor(0,0) {};