# Setting default value for a class property

Tags: c++

I have the function below.  I need to set a generic value for the verbosity level.
Error: Iso C++ forbids isolation.  Do I need to to this through the constructor?

Yes,
I tried that and it worked like this

```
  arche()
    {
    verbosity_ = 1;
    }
```

But as I recall C++ has a special syntax for default member values.  This is probably what I should be using. What is it?

```
  class test
    {
    protected:
      short verbosity_=1; // this does not work
    public:
      void setVerbosity(short v)
        {
        if((v==0 || v==1)) 
          {
          verbosity_ = v;
          }
        else 
          {
          cout << " Verbosity Level Invalid " << endl;
          }
        }
      virtual void runTest() = 0;
    };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [default init value for struct member of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846673/default-init-value-for-struct-member-of-a-class)

Comment: Don't edit the answer into the question.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ 98 and 2003 you cannot do that; you have to do it through the constructor.

In the newest standard, C++11, you are able to use the syntax you're trying.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in the constructor, but you don't need an assignment, you can use initialization syntax like so:

```
test::test() : verbosity_(1)
{
}
```

Comment: which is exactly what Edgars said a couple minutes before I did... I should refresh the page before posting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In C++03 you will need to initialize the short member in the constructor.

As a (limited) workaround, the following would work for integer types:

```
template <class T, T value>
struct defaulted
{
    T val_;
    defaulted(): val_(value) {}  //by default initializes with the compile-time value
    defaulted(T val): val_(val) {}
    operator T() const { return val_; }
};

 class test
    {
    protected:
      defaulted<short, 1> verbosity_;
    public:
      void setVerbosity(short v)
        {
        if((v==0 || v==1))
          {
          verbosity_ = v;
          }
        else
          {
          cout << " Verbosity Level Invalid " << endl;
          }
        }
      virtual void runTest() = 0;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++98 and C++03 you [may](http://www.ideone.com/clone/cgiUg) [only](http://www.ideone.com/cgiUg) initialise `static const` members like that.

```
struct T {
   int x = 3;
};

int main() {
   T t;
   std::cout << t.x;
}

// prog.cpp:4: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘x’
// prog.cpp:4: error: making ‘x’ static
// prog.cpp:4: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘x’
```

```
struct T {
   static const int x = 3;
};

int main() {
   T t;
   std::cout << t.x;
}

// Output: 3
```

Otherwise you [must](http://www.ideone.com/2YDrf) use the ctor-initialiser:

```
struct T {
   int x;
   T() : x(3) {}
};

int main() {
   T t;
   std::cout << t.x;
}

// Output: 3
```

But in C++11 you *can* do that for built-in types: